# Prove Baby Tychonoff's Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Prove that if metric spaces $(X, \rho), (Y, \rho)$ are compact then so is $X$ x $Y$ with product metric.

I don't understand what the product metric is.

I think that the easiest way to do this would be to use the sequential definition of compactness, but I don't know how to proceed

Comment: One example of a product metric is $d((x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2)) = \frac{1}{2} \frac{d_1(x_1,x_2)}{1+d_1(x_1,x_2)} + \frac{1}{4}\frac{d_2(y_1,y_2)}{1+d_2(y_1,y_2)}$ for $X\times Y$ in the more general case for metric spaces $(X,d_1)$ and $(Y,d_2)$, but it seems in your case that $\rho = d_1=d_2$.

From here, it does appear your idea of using sequential compactness will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be defined in whatever you're referring to, but a common choice is $\rho((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2))=(\rho(x_1,x_2)^2+\rho(y_1,y_2)^2)^{1/2}$. There is not really a unique product metric, it just needs to be any metric that metrizes the product topology.

A hint for how to start with the actual problem: given a sequence $(x_n,y_n)$, find a subsequence $n_k$ so $x_{n_k}$ is convergent in $X$. Is $y_{n_k}$ convergent? If so then you're done (because in the product topology, convergence means convergence in each component). If not, what can you do?

Comment: In this definition, are $x_1, y_1$ from $X$ or is it that $x_1, x_2$ are from X and the other two are elements in Y?

Comment: I also have no idea what I can do if $y_{n_k}$ doesn't converge.  Could you please explain?

Comment: @VinnyChase Hint: In the answer above the compactness of $Y$ has not been used yet. How can it be used to conclude the proof?

Comment: @VinnyChase Here $x_1,x_2 \in X,y_1,y_2 \in Y$.

Comment: @CaveJohnson every sequence in Y has a convergent subsequence so use that?

Comment: @ian is the fact that every sequence in Y has a convergent subsequence so $y_{n_k}$ has a convergent subsequence how you complete the proof?

Comment: If you think of balls $B_X(a,r)= \{x \in X: d_X(a,x)<r\}$ a *canonical* choice for the metric on $X\times Y$ is $d_{X\times Y} \big( (x,y),(a,b)\big) = \max\{d_X(x,a),d_Y(y,b)\}$ because then $B_{X\times Y}((a,b),r)=B_X(a,r) \times B_Y(b,r)$.